# Stairs plot with solid horizontal lines and dashed vertical lines in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to create a stairs plot with solid horizontal lines and dashed vertical lines. You can see an example of what I am trying to do in this [question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8833/how-to-compute-the-wavelet-approximation-of-a-function) (scroll down a little bit). In the example, however, they use Python, but I want to do this in MATLAB.

My (simple) code is

```
k=-4:1:4;
a= (2*k +1)/2;
t=-4:0.1:4;

figure()
stairs(k,a,'r')
hold on
plot(t,t)
```

My plot becomes
[image]

I have no idea what to do. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you'll have to draw individual line segments yourself if you really want this in MATLAB, unfortunately...

Comment: There does not seem to be a computational task involved here, but rather a question about plotting with MATLAB.  I would turn to [the MATLAB Newgroup](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/?s_tid=gn_mlc_ng) for advice in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to your original post, with MATLAB you will have to draw the individual line segments. Try this:

```
k=-4:1:4;
a=(2*k +1)/2;
t=-4:0.1:4;
n = size(k,2);

figure(1)
[xb,yb] = stairs(k,a); % gives us the x and y coordinates 
stairs(k,a,'r--'); % the plot
hold on
for i = 1:2:(2*n-2) % size(xb) == size(yb) = 2*n-1
    % overplot black line segments
    plot(xb(i:i+1),yb(i:i+1),'k')
end
```

The end result looks as follows:

[image]